# Spliting name with delimiter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi can you help me to split the name into `firstname`, `middle name`, `lastname` using a pl/sql procedure.

This my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure proc_name(name in varchar2, a out varchar2, b out varchar2,c out varchar2) is
begin
    if regexp_count(name, '/') = 2 then
      a := regexp_substr(name, '[^/]+', 1, 1);
      b := regexp_substr(name, '[^/]+', 1, 2);
      c := regexp_substr(name, '[^/]+', 1, 3);
    end if;
end proc_name;
```

Here is what it should do. Input: `sharmi/devi/elango`

The output is:

```
 firstname:sharmi
 middle name: devi
 lastname : elango
```

I got output for above test cases.

Suppose my input is: `/devi/`

Then my output should be:

```
 firstname: null
 middle name: devi
 lastname: null
```

How could I make it work?

Comment: What happens if you have more than three components? For example this in quite common for Portugiese, e.g. "Sílvio Manuel Azevedo Ferreira Sá Pereira", "Filipe Gui Paradela Maciel da Costa" or "João Alexandre Duarte Ferreira Fernandes" (all famous soccer players)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems with the regexp_substr() calls in your procedure is: sometimes, they return incorrect values - which will be assigned to the 3 variables (a,b,c).  Suppose that there always are 3 "tokens" (first/middle/last name), delimited by '/'.  Each token can either be a "name" or null.  Let's generate some test data, and apply the regexes that you have used in your procedure (Oracle 12c):

```
create or replace view test_data
as
select
  rownum as id
, dt.combinations
, regexp_substr( dt.combinations, '[^/]+', 1, 1) var_a
, regexp_substr( dt.combinations, '[^/]+', 1, 2) var_b
, regexp_substr( dt.combinations, '[^/]+', 1, 3) var_c
from
(
  select
    decode ( T1.token, null, '/', T1.token || '/' )  ||
    decode ( T2.token, null, '/', T2.token || '/' )  ||
    decode ( T3.token, null, '' , T3.token )  as combinations
  from
    ( select null as token from dual union select 'sharmi' from dual ) T1
  , ( select null as token from dual union select 'devi' from dual )   T2
  , ( select null as token from dual union select 'elango' from dual ) T3
) dt ;
```

Selecting from the view gives us:

```
select * from test_data;

ID  COMBINATIONS        VAR_A   VAR_B   VAR_C
1   sharmi/devi/elango  sharmi  devi    elango
2   sharmi/devi/        sharmi  devi
3   sharmi//elango      sharmi  elango        -- incorrect (should be: var_a and var_b)
4   sharmi//            sharmi
5   /devi/elango        devi    elango        -- incorrect (should be: var_b and var_c)
6   /devi/              devi                  -- incorrect (should be: var_b)
7   //elango            elango                -- incorrect (should be: var_c)
8   //
```

Instead of using a procedure, you could use a function (original code: see https://community.oracle.com/thread/925201?start=0&tstart=0 , accessed on 2018-01-06) that returns a table of varchar2, like so:

```
create or replace type split_tbl as table of varchar2(32767);

create or replace function split3
(
    p_list varchar2,
    p_del varchar2 := '/'
) return split_tbl pipelined
is
    l_idx    pls_integer;
    l_list    varchar2(32767) := p_list;
    l_value    varchar2(32767);
begin
    loop
        l_idx := instr(l_list,p_del);
        if l_idx > 0 then
            pipe row( substr( l_list,1,l_idx-1 ) );
            l_list := substr(l_list,l_idx+length(p_del));
        else
            pipe row(l_list);
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return;
end split3;
/
```

For testing this function, you could use something like (explanation below):

```
declare
  combination_ varchar2(128) := '' ;
  result_ split_tbl ;
  type labels is varray(3) of varchar2(16);
  n_label labels := labels(' first name: ',' middle name: ',' last name: ');
begin
  for i in 1 .. 8
  loop
    select
      ' [test case ' || to_char(id) || ']  string -> ' || combinations
    into combination_ from test_data where id = i;

    select * bulk collect into result_
    from table ( split3( ( select combinations from test_data where id = i ) ) ) ;

    dbms_output.put_line( combination_ ) ;

    for token in 1 .. 3
    loop
      dbms_output.put( n_label(token) ) ;
      if result_(token) is null then  dbms_output.put_line( 'null' ) ;
      else dbms_output.put_line( result_(token) ) ;
      end if;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line( '-------------------' ) ;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The anonymous block uses an array of varchar2 values containing labels.  It picks up each of our test cases (from the test_data VIEW), calls the "split" function, and labels (and outputs) its return values.

```
-- output (anonymous block):
[test case 1]  string -> sharmi/devi/elango
 first name: sharmi
 middle name: devi
 last name: elango
-------------------
 [test case 2]  string -> sharmi/devi/
 first name: sharmi
 middle name: devi
 last name: null
-------------------
 [test case 3]  string -> sharmi//elango
 first name: sharmi
 middle name: null
 last name: elango
-------------------
 [test case 4]  string -> sharmi//
 first name: sharmi
 middle name: null
 last name: null
-------------------
 [test case 5]  string -> /devi/elango
 first name: null
 middle name: devi
 last name: elango
-------------------
 [test case 6]  string -> /devi/
 first name: null
 middle name: devi
 last name: null
-------------------
 [test case 7]  string -> //elango
 first name: null
 middle name: null
 last name: elango
-------------------
 [test case 8]  string -> //
 first name: null
 middle name: null
 last name: null
-------------------
```

One of the advantages of the "split" function is: it can also handle more than 3 tokens.  Eg

```
SQL> select * from table(split3(
  2  'João/Alexandre/Duarte/Ferreira/Fernandes'
  3  ))
  4  ;
COLUMN_VALUE  
João          
Alexandre     
Duarte        
Ferreira      
Fernandes
```